Using a menu button with CMFCToolBar in CDialog/CDialogEx
I have this code:
CMenu menu;
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_TOOLBAR_REPORT_VIEWER);  // Load your menu resource
CMenu* pSubMenu = menu.GetSubMenu(0);   // Get the first submenu (or the one you need)
CMFCToolBarMenuButton menuButton(ID_TOOLBAR_REPORT_VIEWER_CONGREGATION, pSubMenu->Detach(), 2, L"123");
m_ToolBar.RemoveButton(2);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(menuButton, 2);
m_ToolBar.AdjustLayout();
m_ToolBar.Invalidate();
m_ToolBar.UpdateWindow();
m_ToolBar.SendMessage(WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI, (WPARAM)FALSE);

It replaces the toolbar icon with a menu button. I have added menu item handlers too (command / update).
But, when I run it the menu items are all disabled. Why?
I have also tried called in OnInitDialog:
UpdateDialogControls(this, false);

Makes no difference. I understood that calling UpdateDialogControls in this manner would ensure that all controls would get processed.
Related

Menu Command Update Handlers in Dialog Boxes
How to customize CMFCMenuBar in an MFC application
Adding a drop-down menu button to a CMFCToolbar, not seeing menu
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/cannot-change-state-menu-item
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/walkthrough-putting-controls-on-toolbars?view=msvc-170

One thing I can say is that OnInitMenuPopup is triggered when the dialogs menu gets displayed, but it does not get triggered when the tool bar button menu gets displayed.
Also, I have tried making a call to m_ToolBar.SetRouteCommandsViaFrame(false); but again, it makes no difference. OnInitMenuPopup is not being triggered when the menu is displayed. So I have no opportunity to update the menu items states.
I have simplified the code:
CMenu menu;
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_TOOLBAR_REPORT_VIEWER);  // Load your menu resource

m_ToolBar.ReplaceButton(ID_MANAGE_REPORT_VIEWER,
    CMFCToolBarMenuButton((UINT)-1, menu.GetSubMenu(0)->Detach(), 2, L"", TRUE));

m_ToolBar.AdjustLayout();
m_ToolBar.AdjustSizeImmediate();
m_ToolBar.SetRouteCommandsViaFrame(false);

But, the result is just the same.

Searched the documentation and your links but couldn't find a straightforward solution. If the framework doesn't provide for such features, then it's not easy to fix it, only delve into the MFC sources and try to make it work. Too much work, for something that will likely be used only once, ie it's not worth. I would rather put all the enable/disable code in a routine and call it from both the dialog's OnInitMenuPopup() (it is triggered, you said) and the button's CMFCToolBarMenuButton::OnClick(). That is, not using the  UpdateUI mechanism, because it doesn't work for dialogs.

@ConstantineGeorgiou unfortunately OnInitMenuPopup is not triggered.

Can you check if OnInitMenu is triggered? I haven't been programming in MFC for years, but IIRC, OnInitMenuPopup is triggered on more modern things like CMFCMenuBar and OnInitMenu  is triggered on old things, like the old raw menus.

And BTW, even before checking that, had you added a WM_INITPOPUPMENU() line on your message map?

@sergiol I already have a properly working OnInitMenuPopup as it is triggered for the main menu MRU updates.

IIRC, try to derive your dialog from CDialogEx instead of  CDialog.

@sergiol All my dialogs are using CDialogEx.

You should refer that in your posting.
